# How to increase players render distance?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

For instance lets say I'm on hypixel playing bed wars.

I get in a match and I want to see players from across the map, but I can only see players that are up to a quarter of the map away.

Other players won't appear farther than that. So I want to know how to see players form across the map.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by, "So I want to see players form across the map." Please explain what you mean by this better

Comment: @THEEPICDUDE990 He wants to increase render distance. As in: He wants to see players that are across the map. Either way, it's a dupe

Comment: It was, I flagged it

Comment: @Oak this is _not_ a duplicate. The distance entities (players, monsters, animals, etc) will become visible to the player is controlled by the server. Increasing the render distance does not affect this. Please reopen.

Answer (score 2):

You can mod your minecraft with optifine to extend your view beyond the normal view plus gives you the ability to zoom in.

Once you have optifine or if you don't get optifine either way you can change your view distance by going in **esc** then raise your **render distance** in there to the max.

**Warning May Cause Lag!**

[Optifine Download link](http://optifine.net/adloadx?f=OptiFine_1.11.2_HD_U_B7.jar)

Answer (score 0):

While on a world or server, hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>, go to options, video settings, and then at the top right corner, there is a bar that says "render distance". Drag the bar to the amount of chunks and there you go!

Comment: This won't always work on a server as they have a settings in Server.Properties that sets the amount of chunks the server will send to the client.